# key-field in cite is cut after three chars

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have some references without an author (e.g. websites) and use the key-field to provide a sorting possibility. Strangely the key field is truncated after 3 characters, both in the cite-command (I use author-year style) and in the bibliography. This looks bad, does anybody have an idea how to change it?
I'm using natbib.

**EDIT:**

(sorry for the late reply, the email notification seems not to work...)

I had to rephrase my question, see below.
First of all here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
  %\bibliographystyle{dinat}
  \bibliographystyle{agsm}
  An eample is given. \citep{example2013title}
  \bibliography{literaturtest}
\end{document}

@misc{example2013title,
    Key = {Example Website},
    Lastchecked = {2013-6-02},
    Publisher = {Website editors},
    Title = {Title of the webpage},
    Url = {http://example.org},
    Year = {2013}
}
```

I found out that the problem is caused by using the bibliography style **agsm**, with **dinat** the key field is not truncated (I must have run LaTeX once less than necessary before to not notice that, sorry!). Unfortunately **dinat** produces German output (e.g. "u.a." instead of "et al.") even I specified English for the babel package. So I would need to rephrase my question:
**How can I get a author-year citation in English without cutting the key-field using the natbib package?**
To answer my own question: I found the **apalike** style doing what I intend.

**But** now the url field is not displayed anymore. I found a **apalike-url.bst** style on the net who should add the url field. But I was wondering if there is no "default" bib style that meets the requirements...?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please provide a small sample latex document with your set-up for `natbib` including which bibliography style you are using.  A simple document for me does not truncate the key.

Answer (score 1):

I do not directly answer your question, but normally an article on a webpage or the webpage itself also has a **author** or at least an **editor**. Here's how you cite a Wikipedia article:

1. Open any [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation)
2. On the left there is a **Toolbox** - click on **Cite this page**. In this example this leads to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aCite&page=Quotation&id=561811291):

   - Page name: Quotation
   - **Author: Wikipedia contributors**
   - **Publisher: Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia.**
   - Date of last revision: 27 June 2013 11:49 UTC
   - **Date retrieved: 3 July 2013 19:48 UTC**
   - **Permanent link: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quotation&oldid=561811291**
   - Primary contributors: Revision history statistics
   - Page Version ID: 561811291

I **highlighted** the important parts.

This is how your `BibTeX` entry could look like:

```
 @misc{wiki:Quotation ,
   author = {Wikipedia},
   title = {Quotation --- Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia},
   year = {2013},
   url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quotation&oldid=561811291},
   note = {Online; accessed 3-July-2013}
 }
```

When you are using `Biblatex` then I would use something like this

```
 @ONLINE{wiki:Quotation,
   author = {Wikipedia},
   title = {Quotation --- Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia},
   year = {2013},
   url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quotation&oldid=561811291},
   urldate = {2013-07-03},
 }
```